# ¿Cómo puedo usar SqlDependency en una consulta con Join y Union a otras tablas?

Tags: c#, sql

```
public class MessagesRepository
    {
        readonly string _connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;

        public IEnumerable<CajaVista> GetAllMessages()
        {

            var ventas = new List<CajaVista>();
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                //using (var command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT VentaID, ClienteID, EstadoID, Fecha FROM dbo.Ventas", connection))
                using (var command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT V.VentaID as Venta,E.Descripcion as Estado, C.Nombre+''+C.Apellido as Nombre, Fecha,Comentarios,'Cliente' as Tipo
                FROM Ventas V 
                JOIN Clientes C ON C.ClienteID = v.ClienteID 
                JOIN Estadoes E ON V.EstadoID = E.EstadoID
                WHERE V.EmpresaID = 1
                union
                SELECT PM.PedidoMesaID as Venta,E.Descripcion as Estado, M.Nombre as Nombre, Fecha,Comentarios,'Mesa' as Tipo
                FROM PedidoMesas PM 
                JOIN Mesas M ON M.MesaID = PM.MesaID 
                JOIN Estadoes E ON PM.EstadoID = E.EstadoID
                WHERE PM.EmpresaID = 1order by Fecha", connection))
                {
                    command.Notification = null;
                    var dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                        connection.Open();

                    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        string coments;
                        //E.Descripcion as Estado, M.Nombre as Nombre, Fecha,Comentarios
                        if (reader["Comentarios"].ToString().Length < 1)
                        {
                            coments = "";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            coments = (string)reader["Comentarios"];
                        } 
                        ventas.Add(item: new CajaVista { VentaID = (int)reader["Venta"], Nombre = (string)reader["Nombre"], Estado = (string)reader["Estado"], Fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Fecha"]), Comentarios = coments, Tipo = (string)reader["Tipo"] });
                    }
                }

            }
            return ventas;
        }

        private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Type.ToString());
            if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
            {
                Hubs.MessagesHub.SendMessages();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [Notificaciones de consulta en SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/t9x04ed2(v=vs.110).aspx)

> La implementación de nivel superior la proporciona la clase **SqlDependency**, que ofrece un alto nivel de abstracción de la funcionalidad de notificación entre la aplicación de origen y SQL Server, lo que permite utilizar una dependencia para detectar cambios en el servidor.
>
> Puede definir notificaciones para las instrucciones SELECT y EXECUTE. Al utilizar una instrucción EXECUTE, SQL Server registra una notificación para el comando ejecutado en lugar de la propia instrucción EXECUTE. El comando debe cumplir los requisitos y **limitaciones de una instrucción SELECT**.

---

## [Crear una consulta de notificación](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms181122.aspx)

### [Instrucciones SELECT admitidas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms181122.aspx)

Se admiten notificaciones de consultas para las instrucciones SELECT que cumplan los requisitos siguientes **(en base a la pregunta)**:

- La instrucción no puede utilizar columnas sin nombre o con nombres duplicados.
- La instrucción no debe incluir los operadores UNION, INTERSECT o EXCEPT.
- La instrucción no debe hacer referencia a los tipos de objetos grandes text, ntext e image.
- ...